# Unusual gap created from images in a table cell

Tags: html, css

```
<tr id='recent_tablerow_0'>
<td>Women's Health Initiative</td>
<td>Versions 1-5: passed embargo</td>
<td>
    <img src="./images/V.png" alt="V" height="24px" width="20.74px" border="0" s>
    <img src="./images/D.png" alt="D" height="24" width="20.74" border="0">
    <img src="./images/A.png" alt="A" height="24" width="20.74" border="0">
    <img src="./images/S.png" alt="S" height="24" width="20.74" border="0">
</td>
<td>55181</td>
<td>Partial Factorial Randomized, Double-Blind, Placebo-Controlled, Cohort, Longitudinal</td>
<td><a href="#">Links</a></td>
<td>N/A</td>
</tr>
```

The images are pushing all the other elements of the other cells down by 24px. Has anyone seen this gap problem before?

Ultimately I would like to remove these images and replace them with 's with the images as background images. But when I do that, there is still a gap and the images appear to be blank, mysteriously.
Advice or similar experiences would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't set 'px' in img width and height attributes.

Comment: I removed the 'px' prefix, but the problem still exists. It's as if the images are creating a horizontal gap for all elements in the row. It seems like its an alignment problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images, by default, are inline elements.  Inline elements have a bit of a gap at the bottom to account for the descenders on letters.  You can probably fix your problem by floating the images.

Comment: floating the images doesn't seem to make a difference.